# PHP File Inclusion Issue: File not Executing as Expected

Tags: php, function, include, execution, inclusion

I'm encountering an issue where a particular PHP file, custom_functions.php, is not being executed within my project, resulting in unexpected behavior.

Problem Context
File Structure:

```
project/
│
├── index.php
├── includes/
│   ├── custom_functions.php
```

Here is a simplified version of the index.php file:

```
<?php

    // Trying to include custom functions file
    include 'includes/custom_functions.php';

    // Using a function from the custom functions file
    $result = customFunction();
    echo "<p>Result: $result</p>";
?>
```

And the custom_functions.php file:

```
    <?php
    function customFunction() {
    return "This function should return a customized value.";
    }
    ?>
```

The issue arises when attempting to include custom_functions.php in index.php. Despite the include statement, the customFunction() isn't being recognized or executed as expected. No errors are displayed, but the function doesn't seem to be available within index.php.

I've tried several solutions:

Checked File Paths: Verified that the file paths are accurate and the custom_functions.php file is in the correct directory.

Error Reporting: Set error_reporting(E_ALL) and ini_set('display_errors', 1) in both files but no errors were displayed.

Direct Function Call: When calling the customFunction() directly within custom_functions.php, it works fine, indicating that the file is being included.

Request for Assistance
I'd greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on why the included file's functions aren't accessible within index.php. Has anyone encountered a similar issue or might know what could be causing this unexpected behavior?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Do you have any other files that would be include and contain a function with the same name ?

Comment: You may want to check with your hosting provider. If you are using a free or low cost provider, they sometimes regard file includes as "feature", making you upgrade to a more expensive solution.

Comment: You should be using `require` instead of `include` to begin with. Your script _needs_ this include file to be able to work, so the attempt to embed it should not just be skipped with a warning as include would do, but make the script die with a fatal error.

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but `include 'includes/custom_functions.php'` does **not** mean _look in the current folder for another folder called "includes" and a file called "custom_functions.php"_. Instead, it means "look in the global includes path for that path, then look in the CWD, and finally look relative to the file. Because of this, I always recommend using absolute paths (or `./` if you really must) to exclude the first two rules. It often doesn't matter, but it can sometimes bite you and makes troubleshooting much easier.

Comment: No, this is just simplified version. (Answered for Nicolas.)

Comment: @CBroe, so it could be that this is the problem? I will look into it, thanks!

Comment: @ChrisHaas, I was clueless. Thank you for providing such a thorough explanation.